# Error loading TeXlive manager 2017

Tags: texlive, installing, texlive-2017

I just installed on a brand new machine the TeXlive 2017 using Enrico Gregorio's [guide](http://profs.scienze.univr.it/~gregorio/texlive-YEAR-ubuntu.pdf).

Everything is fine except for the fact that when I launch the `tlmgr` I get the following error:

```
afcuttin@millenium-falcon:~/idic-comml$ sutlmgr
Loading local TeX Live database
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/tlpkg/texlive.tlpdb)
This may take some time, please be patient ...
bad pad value "2m": must be positive screen distance at 
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl5/5.22/Tk/Widget.pm line 1218.
at /usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/scripts/texlive/tlmgrgui.pl line 295.
Compilation failed in require at /opt/texbin/tlmgr line 4724.
```

the command `sutlmg` is just an alias for `sudo /opt/texbin/tlmgr -gui` as per the installation guide.

Unfortunately it seems that Google is not my friend at finding a solution to this error.

Comment: This seems more a problem with Perl-Tk, rather than with any TeX Live part.

Comment: @egreg thanks for your comment. where do you think it can be more appropriate to notify this issue?

Comment: The TeX Live mailing list seems more appropriate: http://tug.org/mailman/listinfo/tex-live

Comment: further information about this possible bug: the error happens only if my computer (a dell xps 15) is connected to the d3100 docking station (with monitors attached to it). The TeXlive manager works properly if the computer is detached from the docking station.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it probably it is of interest of the TeXlive developers